# Inserting external table of content into another document

Tags: table-of-contents

How do I insert the table of contents of a document into another `LaTeX` document? If this is even possible. 
In the first document, the `ToC` is created using `\tableofcontents`

**edited from comments:**
(partial) MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
 paper=A4, twoside=true, openright, parskip=full, chapterprefix=true,
 11pt, headings=normal, bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc,
 titlepage=on, captions=tableabove, draft=false,
 ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[english]{babel}   
\usepackage[                    
    figuresep=colon,
    sansserif=false,
    hangfigurecaption=false,
    hangsection=true,
    hangsubsection=true,
    colorize=full,
    colortheme=bluemagenta,
]{cleanthesis}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\lstset{breakatwhitespace=false}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx} %allows for including images
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib-refs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
```

`.toc` file:

```
\boolfalse {citerequest}
\boolfalse {citetracker}
\boolfalse {pagetracker}
\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax
\select@language {english}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}{chapter.1} 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1} Expansion Project}{1}{section*.11} 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2} Safety Management}{2}{section*.12} 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  when the first document is processed, a `.toc` file is created.  this contains the information for the table of contents.  if you want to insert this toc into another document, the approach i would take is to copy it under another name, and input that explicitly to the second document.  some additional maneuvering might be needed, such as giving it an appropriate heading, but to be able to say exactly what's necessary, we need more information, preferably in the form of a small example file, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  I tried the suggestions, but  keep getting errors. Undefined control sequence. \ select and Something\s wrong--perhaps a missing\item...{\numberline{1}Introduction{1}{chapter.1} in the toc. file

Comment: please add a small example file plus the `.toc` file (just a few lines of it) that you're trying to insert.  without knowing what document class you're using, we'd just be guessing, which isn't a very profitable use of time.

Comment: @barbarabeeton \documentclass[%
 paper=A4,     
 twoside=true,    
 openright,     
 parskip=full,    
 chapterprefix=true,   
 11pt,      
 headings=normal,   
 bibliography=totoc,   
 listof=totoc,    
 titlepage=on,    
 captions=tableabove,  
 draft=false,  
]{scrreprt}

Comment: @barbarabeeton \boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\select@language {english}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}{chapter.1}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1} Expansion Project}{1}{section*.11}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2} Safety Management}{2}{section*.12}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax

Comment: You could always use pdfpages.

Comment: i've taken the liberty of inserting the code from your comments in the question itself; i hope i've interpreted it correctly.  (you can always edit your own question, and that's the preferred approach.)  but this still doesn't give sufficient information.  what we really need is example code that we can cut-and-paste and use directly for experimental compilation.  this is a useful topic (i've faced it and implemented it before), but it really depends on the packages being used; for example, the `hyperref` elements in the toc file won't transfer successfully.

Comment: is there `\usepackage[<language>]{babel}` in both files?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have inserted all the packages used in the document in the question as well. Hope this helps!

Comment: Please take a look at [this question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for help creating an MWE. In this case, your MWE should give us 2 small, compilable documents with just the packages required to reproduce the problem. This will mean starting with `\documentclass...` for each document, including *relevant* packages, adding enough in the first document to generate a suitable, short ToC, and then showing how you are trying to include the renamed `.toc` file in the second document.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: The suggestions you made are true, but it's not that easy. It requires additional `makeatletter...\makeatother` pairs and the `hyperref` issue was noted already by you.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- thanks for comment (and answer).  in fact, we had just this requirement at ams shortly before the question was asked, and my suggestion reiterated what we did that worked here.  (but we didn't need `hyperref`, and i think our "internal" procedures may better protect against wayward `@`-signed commands in toc files; we insist on `\protect` in cases where a possibly fragile command occurs in a heading.)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to include an external `.toc` file, but tedious and the usability is limited, since the page numbers etc. are not consistent, most likely.

The shown `.toc` file was made with `hyperref`, which complicats the whole issue.

But here's a way:

```
\documentclass[%
 paper=A4, twoside=true, openright, parskip=full, chapterprefix=true,
 11pt, headings=normal, bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc,
 titlepage=on, captions=tableabove, draft=true,final=false
 ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[english]{babel}   
\usepackage[                    
    figuresep=colon,
    sansserif=false,
    hangfigurecaption=false,
    hangsection=true,
    hangsubsection=true,
    colorize=full,
    colortheme=bluemagenta,
]{cleanthesis}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
%
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx} %allows for including images
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib-refs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


%\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
%\lstset{breakatwhitespace=false}


\newcommand{\othercontentsname}{%
  Secondary Contents%
}

% now some code that resembles the `\@starttoc` command 
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\usetocfromothersource}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \IfFileExists{#1}{%
    \chapter*{\othercontentsname}%
    \@input{#1}% 
    \@nobreakfalse
  }{}%
  \makeatother
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\usetocfromothersource{otherdoc.toc}

\part{Some part}
\chapter{Foo}




\end{document}
```

And the `otherdoc.toc`:

```
\boolfalse {citerequest}%
\boolfalse {citetracker}
\boolfalse {pagetracker}
\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax
\select@language {english}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}{chapter.1} 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1} Expansion Project}{1}{section*.11} 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2} Safety Management}{2}{section*.12} 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax
```

Please note that `mcode` changes the section headings etc and seems to be incompatible with `KOMA`.

[image]

Comment: I've just posted a question to extend you solution. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262977.