# Table of Contents from multiple files

Tags: table-of-contents, multiple-files

I have a main document referring to four files and want to create a ToC with the titles of these four files as well as their structure.

Here`s a MWE for my main file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

\input{./title.tex}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

\include{Introduction}
\include{Paper1}
\include{Paper2}
\include{Paper3}

\end{document}
```

and here is an MWE for my included files, all similar:

```
\begin{center}
{\bfseries Title} 
\end{center}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Conceptual Foundations}
\subsection{Topic A}
```

I`d like my ToC to look like:

Title file 1

Section file 1

Subsection File 1

Title file 2

....

Currently I have the problem that the titles are not shown since they have not been labeled as a section (I haven`t done that because I want them to appear as unnumbered titles and the following sections/subsections within the file to appear as section/subsection and not a level lower). The second problem is that the sections after the first file are not numbered but labelled with letters "A", "B", etc - I have an appendix in the first file, not sure whether that influences the rest.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? Use the `report` class instead of `article` and make each paper a `\chapter{}` instead of hand formatting the titles.  Then they will appear in the TOC automatically.  You can use `titlesec` to format the chapter titles the way you want.

Comment: fair enough, that works fine - I guess I can get rid of "Chapter 1" in each title. However, the problem with the numbering still persists - Chaptr 2 is now not Chapter 2, but Chapter A. The reason why I was not using chapter for the titles was that I want a line break within each title itself, e.g. Paper 1

Title of paper 1

Comment: @latexQ: Most likely you have some `\renewcommand{\thechapter}` somewhere that uses `A` instead of a number

Comment: @latexQ: By the way, I answered a question recently about including external toc from other documents: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262977/inserting-external-table-of-content-into-another-document/286484#286484

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sample document to get you started. I've used `titlesec` to format the chapter headings and the `appendix` package to make use of its `{subappendices}` environment.  The reason your chapters are mislabeled is that the default `\appendix` command turns `\chapter` level headings into appendices. Since you want per chapter appendices you need to make appendices as section level elements. So you need to remove the `\appendix` commands from your included documents and then enclose the appendix sections in the `{subappendices}` environment.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\filcenter\Large\bfseries}%
  {}{1em}{}
\usepackage{appendix}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\setthesection}{\Alph{section}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Paper title one}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{A chapter appendix}
\section{Another chapter appendix}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Paper title two}
\section{A section}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{An appendix}
\end{subappendices}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Ok, now I understand where the problem was - thank you, it works just as expected!